# Sequilize migrate not running new code

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I need to create a new field in a database table. Then I run the following:

```
sequelize migration:create
```

A new file called

```
DATETIME_unnamed-migration.js
```

is created.

I open that file and write this in the up-function:

```
queryInterface.addColumn(
    'User',
    'postcode',
    Sequelize.STRING
)
```

I then run

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

The table User has now a new field called "postcode".

So what now? I have a file named

```
DATETIME_unnamed-migration.js
```

Next time I need to add a new field, what do I do?
If I try to modify the file above and then run db:migrate again nothing happens.
On the console I see:

```
No migrations were executed, database schema was already up to date.
```

So sequelize-cli doesn't care that one of my old migration files changed?
Do I need to create a new migration-file every time I need to add new things in database schema?
Then after a while the directory with migration files will be full.
Is this the ordinary approach or am Imissing something?

Answer (score 2):

> With migrations you can transfer your existing database into another
>   state and vice versa: Those state transitions are saved in migration
>   files, which describe the way how to get to the new state and how to
>   revert the changes in order to get back to the old state.

I believe that the idea of migration files is to keep track of changes and updates of database schema. So you will have to create a new migration file everytime you want to update your database schema.